# DynamoDb scan returning get, set and Observer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

[image]

"Items" are the data I needed, but all these gets and sets where are they coming from?
I double-check my dynamo DB there are no such columns. I am using aws API gateway to handle my request. Should I just ignore this? My front end is using vue.js along with serverless and was service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These methods aren't coming from AWS (DynamoDB, API Gateway, etc).  These are artifacts of Vue.

You can check out the Vue [documentation on Reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) for more in depth information.